# Margenes con iText en Java

Tags: java, servlets, itext

Estoy generando un PDF en Java el tema es que no he podido configurar el margen, ya que lo necesito con margen NORMAL (superior e inferior 2.5cm, derecho e izquierdo 3 cm)

Este es el codigo en mi servlet para el doc

```
        /**CREACION DOCUMENTO**/
        Phrase      saltoLinea      =   new Phrase((Chunk.NEWLINE));
        Document    documento       =   new Document(PageSize.LEGAL_LANDSCAPE);
        documento.setMargins(60, 60, 0, 50); // (izq, der, arriba, abajo)
        PdfWriter   writer          =   PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, byteArrayOutputStream);
        HeaderFooterPageEvent event =   new HeaderFooterPageEvent();
        writer.setPageEvent(event);
        documento.open();
```

el problema es documento.setMargins(60, 60, 0, 50) donde no se en que medida toma esos parametros

Answer (score -1):

Hago un intento de responder pero hay que decir que iText no tiene una documentación muy extensa.

Teniendo en cuenta que en iText-5.0.5 y 4.2.1 el tamaño de una página A4 es:

```
public static final Rectangle A4 = new RectangleReadOnly(595.0F, 842.0F);
```

y en la vida real el formato A4 tiene 210 x 297 mm, podemos deducir que la relacion es 2,83, mas o menos.

Entonces los margenes que estás poniendo deben de ser algo como (21mm, 21mm, 0, 18mm).

Lo que te puedo aconsejar es probar y rectificar hasta que te guste.

Una cosa que he notado es que no están "doblando" el lado corto de la hoja. A3 no es 842.0F x 1190.0F lo que debería ser si doblamos 595, sino 842.0F, 1191.0F. A2 cuadra, pero A1 se sube con 2.0F y A0 con otro tanto.